# A $p$-group action on a cartesian product.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions, sylow-theory, direct-product

Let $p$ be a prime number. Let $S$ be a group of order $p^r$ and $T$ a set with $m$ elements. Let $$E=\{A\subset S\times T\ |\ |A|=p^r\}.$$
Then, the mapping $\phi:S\rightarrow\mathfrak{S}_{S\times T},\,s\mapsto((x,y)\mapsto(sx,y)),$ is a group homomorphism. Let 
$$\hat{\phi}:S\rightarrow\mathfrak{S}_{\mathfrak{P}(S\times T)}, s\mapsto (A\mapsto\phi_s(A)),$$
be the canonical extension of this action to $\mathfrak{P}(S\times T)$. Note that $E\subset\mathfrak{P}(S\times T)$ is stable under this operation; hence $S$ operates on $E$. Let
$$E^S:=\{A\in E\ |\ (\forall s)(s\in S\implies\phi_s(A)=A)\}.$$

> I want to show that 
>   $$E^S=\{Y\ |\ (\exists t)(t\in T\ \&\ Y=S\times\{t\})\}.$$

**Attempt:**

Let $A\in E^S$: then $A\subset S\times T$ such that $|A|=p^r$ and $\phi_s(A)=A$, for all $s\in S$. This means that $A\ne\emptyset$: let $z\in A$. I have to show that there exists $t\in T$ such that $A=S\times\{t\}$.

Is $pr_2(z)$ a good candidate for $t$? I am not able to show that $A=S\times\{pr_2(z)\}$. Alternatively, what could $t$ be?

Comment: What is $pr_2(z)$?

Comment: Second projection of $z$: e.g. if $z=(x,y)$, then $pr_2(z)=y$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A\in E^S$ nonempty and $(x,t)\in A$. Then $x\in S$ and so for $x^{-1}\in S$ we have
$$\phi_{x^{-1}}((x,t))=(e,t)\in A,$$
where $e\in S$ denotes the identity element. It follows that for every $s\in S$ we have
$$\phi_s((e,t))=(s,t)\in A,$$
and so $S\times\{t\}\subset A$. Because $|A|=|S|=|S\times\{t\}|$ it follows that $A=S\times\{t\}$.

Conversely, for every $t\in T$ the set $A_t:=S\times\{t\}$ satisfies $A_t\in E^S$.

Comment: So given $A\in E^S$, what is the candidate which you propose for $t$?

Comment: I have shown that every $A\in E^S$ is of the form $A=S\times\{t\}$ for some $t\in T$. What more is there to say? Yes, this clearly shows that $t$ is the projection onto the second coordinate of every element of $A$.

Comment: Suppose $u\in A$: why should $u\in S\times\{t\}$ for some $t$? I should be able to write $u$ in the form $(s,t)$ for some $s\in S$. How do you know such a $t$ exists?

Comment: This is precisely what my answer shows; what part of the argument do you not understand?

Comment: I am not clear about the existence of this $t$. Where do you get it from? Will any $t\in T$ do?

Comment: Also do you mean to write $(x,t)$ instead of $(x,y)$ in the first sentence of your answer?

Comment: @khwar Yes I did, corrected! The existence of this $t$ is simply; if $A\in E^S$ then $A$ is nonempty, so it contains an element. Every element of $A$ is of the form $(x,t)$ with $x\in S$ and $t\in T$. That is where $t$ comes from.

Comment: Great, now it makes sense. Last question: why is it the case that $|A|=|S|$?

Comment: By definition if $A\in E$ then $|A|=p^r=|S|$.